# How do I rice my Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: unity, gnome-shell, lightdm, customization

I saw a few of the posts on r/unixporn with beautiful layouts and styled desktops with beautiful icons.
While the only thing I have done is position my dock on the right lol.

I recently had an issue with my graphics driver and the screen was black on login. Someone answered my question on here and I changed the display manager to Lightdm which completely fixed the problem.
but the desktop looks exactly the same and I want to change it.
it seems that people usually have different distros looking incredible, like arch.
I was wondering if I can do the same with Ubuntu

TLDR:
what can I do to spice up my desktop?
Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install a program called `gnome-tweaks` (if it's not already installed), download themes from the internet (Google search Ubuntu themes). A good website to download Ubuntu themes is https://pling.com. GNOME tweaks will allow you to install these themes the easy way.

To install `gnome-tweaks` run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks`.

Also, there are various other window managers. One that I really like is called Cinnamon. To install, run `sudo apt-get install cinnamon`.

Another cool window manager is called AwesomeWM, try running `sudo apt-get install awesome`. For key bindings, view https://datapioneer-network.org/index.php/2021/03/13/awesome-window-manager-installation-and-set-up/

Another one is called KDEPlasma. To install, run `sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop`. Note: If your graphic card sucks, running this might be an issue.

Comment: Thank you I will try this out. I've never heard of Gnome-tweaks before. This should be fun!

Comment: Yep. Have fun doing whatever you're doing...

Comment: I added some more stuff.

Comment: Thank you! I can't wait! My desktop is gonna be beautiful! Soon I will have something to post on r/unixporn too!

Comment: @BarryScott Isn't it funny how they call it UnixPorn?! LMAO

Comment: Ya it's pretty funny lmao! I think there is a LinuxPorn too. but people mostly post on the Unix subreddit.